# Is there any way to use a 500G 2.5" SATA HDD with a computer with an old i845 chipset?

Tags: hard-drive, adapter, pata, msata

I have an old computer lying around that uses the Intel i845 chipset. It is conencted to a 40GB, 5800RPM 3.5" Seagate ST340015A Ultra ATA HDD that recently went kaput.

It uses an 80-conductor 40-pin Ultra ATA/100 cable to connect to the motherboard. I have a spare 500GB, 5400 RPM 2.5" Hitachi Travelstar HK500.B SATA HDD that I would like to connect to this ancient computer if it's possible.

The HK500.B HDD is an internal HDD meant for notebooks and has an SATA interface that looks like this:

[image: SATA interface]

I checked out a few IDE to SATA adapters online that I think might help, but they all look a little different from each other so I'm not sure which one to get.

I saw this adapter at: http://www.cooldrives.com/satoidecofor.html
[image: http://www.cooldrives.com/satoidecofor.html]

and this one at: http://shopping.rediff.com/product/ide-to-sata-sata-to-ide-hdd-converter-cable/10366312?sc_cid=search

[image: http://shopping.rediff.com/product/ide-to-sata-sata-to-ide-hdd-converter-cable/10366312?sc_cid=search]

If you have used any such other adapters, or know the right one for the job, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PATA had two varient interfaces - the one on top is for desktops - using a 40 pin connector and molex for power and a 44 pin connector for laptops which included power. The latter is for laptop drives with a single connector doing both power and data.

SATA has a single interface, and the connectors are the same. You can use any drive thats small enough to fit in your bay - I use a mix of 7mm and 9mm thick 2.5 inch drives and regular 3.5 inch hard drives. The separation between the power and sata connectors are standard and you should be able to fit either adaptor with no issues. The first adaptor will connect directly to the drive and is the correct one - it will connect to the same molex power adaptor and 40 pin connector on the PC side, and the sata connectors will 'just fit' - though I'm not entirely sure if such an adaptor can be used for a boot drive, or how reliable they are - some people report problems with them. It might be worth looking at reviews to check before you buy one for a boot drive

The second adapter is for connecting a *pata* laptop HDD to a desktop, and is entirely unsuitable for your use

Another option might be to find a pci-sata controller and use that instead. They arn't terribly expensive if you shop around, and might end up being much less finicky.

Comment: I agree on using a controller. They cost just about as much as the converter and are MUCH more reliable. Converters often introduce subtle compatibility issues. Controllers also have better performance even on a PCI bus. (Converter is limited to PATA speed, while even the slowest SATA drive can do about 1.5x better.) Be careful to buy a PCI controller. PCI-e is much more common these days, but won't fit in your old motherboard.

Comment: Thank you JourneymanGeek and @Tonny for your quick response.

I'm sorry if this sounds stupid, but found a PCI to SATA controller card on Ebay that has 2 SATA data connector ports but I don't see a power connector port on the card.

Would this work for the purpose of connecting the laptop hard drive to the PC? [link](http://www.ebay.in/itm/PCI-to-SATA-HDD-adaptor-CONVETER-Card-3-Sata-1-IDE-port-/141120010736)

And will I be able to boot from the SATA drive if I use the controller card?

Comment: you use a power connector from your power supply. If you lack a sata power connector, you use a molex -> sata power adaptor.

Comment: Will I be able to boot off the SATA drive using the controller card?

Comment: Usually - check up the specific model before you buy however

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll order one and see how it goes. My desktop computer has a really old Award Modular BIOS v6 from 2002 but it has a lot of options to tweak, unlike modern notebook BIOSes.

Comment: You can boot just fine of the controller. The BIOS will typically see it as a SCSI controller or a "add-in storage controller". You just set that as the boot-device and of you go. Please be aware that when installing Windows you may have to load additonal drivers for the SATA controller very early in the install process. In XP you have to press F6 when the message (briefly) shows on-screen. Vista and later will prompt automatically for it, if needed (it is possible they support the controller out-of-the box).

Comment: @Vinayak If there is a newer bios it is a very good idea to upgrade it. A bios that old may not play nice with newer Windows versions and SATA controllers. It will work, but it could work better with a later bios. (If there is a newer avialable of course.)